# Screenflow based application in Adobe Flex/Flash

Tags: flash-cs4, flexbuilder, flex4

I'm searching for some code samples for my Flash application. The app is based on screen-flows , i.e each screen is defined with some visual elements with some buttons which have async events associated with them(consuming web services basically). The buttons also have functionality to go back and forth between screens and jump to any screen. I want to define all of the visual elements and the functionality of the events in a XML file. Thus the model, view and controller are all in the XML. Does any framework allow this like Pure MVC? Where can I find some examples of this kind of functionality that I want?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Flash implementation of Heirarchical State Machines here, which mentions XML and Flow Control:

http://code.google.com/p/troyworks/

*(Note: There's a very slick screencasting application [called Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) which may lay claim on that particular term these days...)*